# Git post receive hook is not running

Tags: git, hook, git-post-receive

I searched through questions but it did not answer my question still.

Most of them suggest to set permissions, so the file could be executed. Done that - set to 777.

Transport protocol has to be not http, but ssh. I hope it is, in the git extensions I checked browse repositories - it is starting with git@bitbucket.org so it should be ssh protocol.

post-receive simply looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -x

echo 'test';

git log -1 HEAD --pretty=format:"%x09%ad%x09";

touch ~/repos/develop/dashboard/test.txt;
```

So when I run git pull, those should be executed.

I tried to rename post-receive to post-checkout - then it was executed when calling git checkout.

But with git pull - post-receive is like ignored.

Also some mentioned noexec partitions. But I hope that if post-checkout is working, then this also has to be working, because post-checkout also needs to be executed.

What else should I check?

**Update:**

I will tell why I choose this hook, and maybe you can suggest another way.

I want on git pull to call some link which will save the current date to the database. So when user opens website - he could see when the website was last updated, so I would not need manually set the time on each site update.

**Update:**
Ok, I see interesting line:

> These scripts run before and after pushes to the server.

I push to server from my computer which I write code.
How can my ubuntu server know that I have pushed? Should I put the post-receive file in my computer which I program and push? I can try, but somehow it looks impossible that it will help.

**Update**

Tried putting post-receive in my computer which I use to push and as I expected - no test.txt was created in ubuntu server, nor in my computer.

**Update**

How I achieved what is to use **post-merge** hook. It is client side category. My server is a client relatively to bit bucket it means. So when I pull to my server, merging is done and so my script is executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These scripts (pre-receive, post-receive and update) run before and after pushes to the server, not on client side.

So you need to check out [client side hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

**tldr;** There is no specific hook after git pull.

Comment: I put them in server .git/hooks folder of my project

Comment: If there is no hook after git pull, then how post-receive is executed? So I was trying hard to execute with the wrong command? Btw I have read your link but I can't solve the problem still

Comment: Receive in `post-receive` means that server is received push (you push, server receive and), not other way around (you pull, you receive). Because of that post-receive hook is on server side.

Comment: I agree that server receive. But how server knows? Or which server are we talking about at first? I think push is received by bit bucket or whatever site where it is main repository  or how should I call it. So in bit bucket I will not put a file, I have no acces to their linux server.

Comment: Git server, in your case bitbucket, so basically you can't use server side hooks because you do not have access to actual git server, it's on bitbucket side. So you can only use client side hooks, those hooks will be executed on you local machine when you merge, amend or do something else with git (locally).

Comment: oh, so that should be the first thing mentioned in this book. Probably those lot of questions are not getting why this does not work, because they might think same as me that it should work on pull. And so it means I could create my version of bit bucket, right? But its overkill I guess :D

Comment: Basically yes, you can have one server where you have installed git as server, and then you push your code to it (without any web interface of course :)). It's like web server but for git.